# Реализация кривой с цифрами

Tags: html, css

Как лучше сделать будет через backround-image и через абсолютное позиционирование элементов-это нормальный способ? или только canvas?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Единственная проблема с `backround-image` - это потеря резкости при изменении "родных" размеров в случае адаптивности. Других проблем не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё как вариант можно использовать SVG. У вас картинка по сути векторная, и её очень хорошо и красиво можно сделать на SVG.

Так же все тексты можно прямо в SVG обёртке и сделать, и тогда даже и не придётся париться с координатами и позиционированием.

Всё же фон и тексты это два слоя, и надо позаботиться об их синхронизации, тогда как SVG был бы одним объектом и всё было бы в его координатах.

Comment: Чем же плох вариант с бекграундом для адаптивности? в процентах задавай себе позицию и всего-то ... а вообще, это конечно не ответ, с другой стороны какой вопрос ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev ну если на мобильном это отобразить просто изменив масштаб не думаю что очень красиво будет, например можно убрать лишние концы, и акцент сделать на центровой части, что бы тексты и точки были более видны. Всё-таки адаптивность и просто растяжка это разные вещи. Но с другой стороны на SVG сталкиваемся с этим же вопросом. Но с другой стороны можно сделать SVG + JavaScript.

Comment: ну, тут уже зависит от нужной адаптивности ... я сам за svg и canvas (особенно за второй) в подобных задачах, но не понимаю категоричного "не дадут" ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev хорошо, принимаю поправку